# How does this animation work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, cookies

I'm working with cookies to run or not run a jQuery animation someone else built:

```
 $(function () {
     $('div.transitional').click(function () {
         $('div.intro').removeClass('hidden');
         $('div.final').off('click');
     });

     ShowDiv($("div.transitional.hidden")[0]);
 });

 function ShowDiv(target) {
     target = $(target);
     target.removeClass('hidden');

     target.delay(500).animate({
         opacity: 1.0
     }, 300, 'easeInExpo', function () {
         ShowDiv($("div.transitional.hidden")[0]);
     })
 }
```

I have the cookie part working, but I'm confused about the anonymous function and the "ShowDiv" function.

What is each part doing?

Functionally, the animation makes visible a series of pictures, then the whole site. I want to skip the animation and just make the whole site visible (if cookies='visited'.) I'd like to do this without rewriting the animation script.

Here's a link: http://claytonsalem.com/bottlecap.

What happens now is if you have the cookie the animation doesn't run and everything is hidden.

Comment: Your link is behind a security login... Please stick the relevant parts in a JSFiddle.

Comment: `$(function () {` is just a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){`

Answer (score 0):

That script only fades in elements, one after the other. If you want to skip that, use something like this in the anonymous function (which is also known as a DOM ready handler) :

```
$(function() {
    $('div.transitional').click(function() {
        $('div.intro').removeClass('hidden');
        $('div.final').off('click');
    });

    if(cookies === "visited") //Assuming you already have the variable set.
        ShowDiv($("div.transitional.hidden")[0]);
    else
        $("div.transitional.hidden").css('opacity', 1).removeClass('hidden')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I will focus on how it works:

```
$("div.transitional.hidden")
```

This would select ALL elements with `div.transitional.hidden`, placing them in a list.

By placing `[0]` in the selector, we are picking ONLY the first element in this list.

Then, when the script begins to run, this element is modified by `target.removeClass('hidden')`, which removes the hidden class.

When the scripts ends, it calls the `$("div.transitional.hidden")[0]` selector again, but this time it will not include the previously selected element (because it no longer has the `hidden` class).

That's why the script show images one after the other: it removes the `hidden` class and selects the next remaining element.

You might refer to Karl's answer on how to show your whole site.

Comment: I'll work on a jsfiddle version. Thanks for the explanation of the Showdiv function. I get now why it calls itself, it's like it's looping through until there's nothing in the `div.transitional.hidden` list. However, I'm not sure what's happening in the anonymous function with the `.click` method. Why is that called? The animation runs without any interaction with the site except for reloading.

Comment: Are you referring to the anonymous function in the upper level itself, or the function inside the click event?

Comment: inside the click event. why or what `.off('click')` i probably need to recreate this in jsfiddle b/c there seems to be no clicking in the animation, it just runs on loading the page.